# javascript / jquery cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, hyperlink

did anyone knows how to create a cookie and get the value?
i have some list with the hyperlink and i dont know to use the cookie with javascript or jquery.

this is an example hyperlink

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="about_me">About me</a></li>
 <li><a href="reference">reference</a></li>
 <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

if some user click on about_me or reference cookies chould be remembered.
thank you so much for any kind of help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Show what you've tried and where you've failed and let the community help guide you, not from scratch for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via jQuery then you need to add one library of jQuery jquery.cookie.js like

and put the code as below:
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("ul > a").click(function(){
           // to set the cookie.
             $.cookie('hrefatt', $(this).attr(href));
        });
    })
if you need to do this via javascript :
create function as below
      function setcookie(cookiename,cookieval,expires)
      {
         document.cookie = cookiename+ "=" + cookieval+ "; " + expires;
     }

and call this function as below:

```
   <ul>
        <li><a href="home" onclick="setcookie('hrefcookie','home',1)">Home</a>   
       </li>
         <li><a href="about_me" onclick="setcookie('hrefcookie','about_me',1)">About me</a></li>
         <li><a href="reference" onclick="setcookie('hrefcookie','reference',1)">reference</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact" onclick="setcookie('hrefcookie','contact',1)">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
      </pre>
```

Comment: thanks again for your great answer. i have tried with jquery but i don't know if this correct. $('ul a').on('click', function(){
     var co = $.cookie;
     var txt = $(this).text()
     co = 'expires=Fri, 15 May 2015 14:40:00 UTC; path=/' + txt + '';
     console.log(co);
    });
   });